# java lang NoClassDefFoundError CommandLineParser

Tags: java, hdfs

I create a server web to GET data from `HDFS`.
I'm trying to run it using command line.

command:

```
java -cp jar1.jar:* package_name
```

I got the following error:

```
Server web for testing !16:07:01.741 [main] INFO 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:....../hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance() 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
16:07:01.934 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName - Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:651) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:162) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:159) 
 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:774) 
 at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:159) 
 at .<init>(myclassClient.java:53) 
 at (myclass1.java:186) 
 at (myclass1.java:161) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser 
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:766) 
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) 
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1083) 
 ... 17 more
```

As my understanding, the error came from the exception below, I had a look on it, on the forums:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser
```

It seems the `common-cli.jar` file is missing, I added it, I got an
infinity of errors. I deleted it.

If you remark in the stack trace, the error came from line 53 in `myclassClient.java:53` and `myclass1.java:186`

line 53 is:
`hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI((String)hadoop_conf.get("fs.defaultFS")), hadoop_conf, user);`

line 186 from myclass1 class is:

```
try(HdfsClient hdfsClient = new HdfsClient(nameNodeHosts, "hive"))
```

I'm looking for the solution, if someone can suggest me a solution it will appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to add the Commons CLI library _and all its dependencies_ and all the dependencies of its dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing anyone would be able to tell you, in this case, is what the JVM output is telling us; the same thing you have already noticed, the org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser is missing. It is possible that when you add the library to the classpath, the runtime finds the missing class but fails again. What fails when you add the library?